# WCF Service Method - Refactoring for Unit Test and Mocking

Tags: wcf, unit-testing

I've a WCF service with the following method:

```
Public Function ScheduleEmail(ByVal request As ScheduleEmailRequest) As     ScheduleEmailResponse _
    Implements EmailProtocol.ISchedulingService.ScheduleEmail

    Try
        If Not Email.IsValidEmailAddress(request.EmailAddress) Then
            EmailSchedulerTrace.Source.WriteError(String.Format("Email with template   '{0}' was not sent to '{1}' because it the address is invalid.", request.EmailName, request.EmailAddress))
        Else
            Dim mgr As New JobManager
            Dim job As New EmailJob
            Dim suppression As New SuppressionManager

            Dim emailItem As Email = Email.GetEmailByName(request.EmailName)
            If suppression.CheckSuppresion(emailItem, request.EmailAddress) Then
                job.JobGuid = Guid.NewGuid
                job.EmailAddress = request.EmailAddress
                job.EmailGuid = emailItem.ID
                job.ScheduledSendTime = request.ScheduledTime
                job.CustomAttributes = request.CustomAttributes
                job.ConsumerID = Email.GetConsumerId(request.CustomAttributes)

                mgr.ScheduleJob(job)
            Else
                EmailSchedulerTrace.Source.WriteWarning(String.Format("Email with template '{0}' was not sent to '{1}' because it was suppressed.", request.EmailName, request.EmailAddress))
            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailSchedulerTrace.Source.WriteError(ex)
        Throw
    End Try

    Return New ScheduleEmailResponse

End Function
```

I need to write Unit Test for this Method. Please help me out with

- Do i need to change anything in my method?
- What should I mock?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Sachin

Comment: 1. Yes, you need make some changes to the method. 2. Hard to say without knowing what happens in the constructor for JobManager, EmailJob and SuppressionManager. But by looking at your code you need to be able to mock (mgr As New JobManager). And one way of doing that is using injection. check out the moq framework!

Comment: there is nothing in the constructor of the JobManager. The JobManager class has got methods to schedule and unschedule email. These methods use the methods of the JobData class - which is responsible to make entries in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to *swap out* any 'services' (classes that you `new` up in a method or fields in the class) which connect to other systems (database, email server etc) so you need to create `interface`s for the classes and inject the correct implementation at runtime and in your unit test, you can create `mock` or `fake` implementations for testing purposes.

A good start would be to define an interface for:

- `JobManager`
- `EmailSchedulerTrace`
- `SuppressionManager`

You also might need to move the functionality of your static methods on `Email`

- `GetEmailByName`
- `GetConsumerId`

if they encapsulate database access or any other service which you cannot isolate.

Comment: Hi Trevor...thanks for your answer...got your first point of creating interfaces...i have got a question: 1) what do you exactly mean moving the functionality of static methods 'GetEmailByName' and 'GetCosumerId'. They surely do encapsulate database.

Comment: You will need to create a separate class to expose those methods which you can then expose via an interface to your service. If you don't to that, any tests which call that method will also require access to a database with the expected values in it - that becomes more of an integration test, unit tests are about isolating code from specific implementation details - that's where the mock/fakes come in. You can define the behavior of the mock to test a specific scenario & it's not dependent on a database or web service etc.